# Which DOSGi in Karaf 3.0?

Tags: karaf

I am trying to validate Distributed OSGi using Karaf.  I have two Karaf instances, one with a RESTful interface that calls into an OSGi service.  This is all working fine.  I have used

- Karaf 3.0.3
- Installed the http feature
- Added the feature repo for Apache CXF 3.1.0
- Installed the feature cxf

I've written my test code fine... I can call the service from my browser just fine.

Now I want to use DOSGi to call that restful service from another Karaf instance.  I've been trying to use [Apache CXF for Distributed OSGi](http://cxf.apache.org/distributed-osgi-reference.html), but I can never install the feature.  It complains about unresolved dependencies.  Somewhere in the dosgi code, it doesn't want any cxf library newer that 3.0, but I'm using 3.1.0 of CXF.  And I have trouble installing older versions of CXF in Karaf 3.0

Now, I've noticed that there is [Cellar](http://karaf.apache.org/index/subprojects/cellar.html), which has (as part of that) a DOSGi implementation.  Should I be using that instead?

Any thoughts on how DOSGi can get running on Karaf 3.0 would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have been able to use Cellar's DOSGi support successfully in a Karaf 3.0 environment.  I still have not been able to get cxf-dosgi working in Karaf 3.0.  Unless I spend more time on cxf-dosgi, cellar might be the go for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check https://cxf.apache.org/distributed-osgi-greeter-demo-walkthrough.html there is also an example dosgi samples

```
C:\felix-framework-3.0.1>

Welcome to Apache Felix Gogo
g! install http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/osgi/org.osgi.compendium/4.2.0/org.osgi.compendium-4.2.0.jar
g! start http://www.apache.org/dist/cxf/dosgi/1.2/cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution-1.2.jar
... some log messages may appear...
g! lb
    0|Active     |    0|org.apache.felix.framework (3.0.1)
    1|Active     |    1|org.apache.felix.bundlerepository (1.6.2)
    2|Active     |    1|org.apache.felix.gogo.command (0.6.0)
    3|Active     |    1|org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime (0.6.0)
    4|Active     |    1|org.apache.felix.gogo.shell (0.6.0)
    5|Resolved   |    1|osgi.cmpn (4.2.0.200908310645)
    6|Active     |    1|cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution (1.2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Karaf 3.0 is a little old in the meantime, but for anyone looking for a more recent integratio, look at
https://github.com/apache/aries-rsa